# Modify a function to return a pointer to the last letter in a word from a string

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, printing

well I have problem with my exercise. I have a task that tell me that I have to modify a function (***skipWords()***) so that it instead of returning a pointer to the first letter in the chosen word, it returns a pointer to the last letter in the same word. Looks like I may not change anything in any other function than ***skipWords()***.

Here is an **EXECUTION EXAMPLE**:

Write a sentence: **greetings to you**
Which word do you want to print? **1**
**o**

**My code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<strings.h> // We include this library to manipulate text strings.
#include<ctype.h>
#define SIZE 100
int printFirstWord(char *pointer)
{
    int i;
    int length=strlen(pointer);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(pointer[i])!=0)
        {
            printf("%c",pointer[i]);
        }
        else if(isalpha(pointer[i])==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
char *skipWords(char sentence[],int words)
{
    int count=0,x,i;
    int length=strlen(sentence);
    char *pointer;

    if(words==0)
    {
        pointer=&sentence[0];
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(isalpha(sentence[i])==0)
            {
                x=i+1;
                count=count+1;
                pointer=&sentence[x];
            }
            if(i==(length-1))
            {
                pointer=NULL;
                break;
            }
            if(count==words)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}
void printWord(char sentence[], int wordNumber)
{
    char *pointer;
    int length;
    length=strlen(sentence);
    int i;
    pointer=skipWords(sentence,wordNumber);
    if(pointer==NULL)
    {
        printf("This word doesn't exist");
        return ;
    }
    printFirstWord(pointer);
}
int main()
{
    char sentence[SIZE];
    int length;
    int words;
    int check=1;

    while(check==1)
    {
        printf("Write a sentence; ");
        gets(sentence);
        length=strlen(sentence);
        printf("\nWhich word should be printed? ");
        scanf(" %d",&words);
        printWord(sentence, words);
        printf("\n Do you want to enter a new sentence (press 1 to say yes)?");
        scanf("%d",&check);
        getchar();
    }
return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure what I have to modify, I tried most of the afternoon and all my attempts to get it failed.

Comment: Where does skipWords currently set the pointer it returns (ie-where is it currently setting the pointer to the *first* letter of the word)?

Comment: You tried most of the afternoon and all of your attempts failed. Tell us about said attempts please.

Comment: Okay, I tried a few times changing the loops and see if I could points  to the end of the sentence but no more. And I spent most of the afternoon finishing this assignment and now this is the last task that I have to do. Is almost 2:00 am and I have to send this before 8:00 am. I know that this can't be complicated but I'm just asking for some indications or clues of what to do.

Comment: @AntónPomboAmarelle Consider the cases in the function `skipWords`. As it is right now your main `if else` statement revolves around the argument `int words`. What happens with the code as it is when `words == 0`? Is this the same thing that you want to have happen? Now consider `words != 0`. What happens there? Is this what you want to have happen? If it's still not clicking, go through the code and add a comment to each line describing what it does.

Comment: I know that I have the answer is to modify the content of the loops. For example after the words == 0, the pointer points to the beginning of the sentence but I do not know if the solution (to this first point) is to change &sentence [0] to & sentence [length-1]. Testing I have verified that if in words == 0, I change to &sentence [length-1] and then when I am asked what word I want to print, if I say 0 the last letter of the last word is printed, just as I want it. But if I say that if I enter 1 I get the word that occupies the position 1 of the sentence, which I do not want.

Comment: EXAMPLE:        -------------------                     Write a sentence: Hello my friend    ----------------------                                   Which word should be printed? 0    --------------------                        output: d   ---------------                  
      Write a sentence: Hello my friend -------------------                                       Which word should be printed? 1 --------------------                        output: my

Comment: Yeeeahhh I got it!!!! Thank you @bigwillydos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to have a Number inside your sentence, because isalpha only checks for Letters.

I changed some Variable names and used a fixed sentence and word but that doesn't change the program.

All I did (I think) was changing the printFirstWord fkt.

See the Code here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df75d62b5aa338f3